# Create PDF form with LibreOffice. Signature field

Tags: pdf, digital-signature, libreoffice, pdf-form

I am creating a PDF form with LibreOffice. I would like to add a signature field in this document.

Is it possible withs this tool or is it necessary to use another tool?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I think is not possible to use LibreOffice for inserting a signature field that allow to insert a digital signature based in a certificate. So, my final solution is based in the use of iText. When I have the PDF form, I use Java program that it cab insert this signature fiedl in yhe PDF:

```
PdfReader pdf = new PdfReader("in.pdf");
        PdfStamper stp = new PdfStamper(pdf, new FileOutputStream("out.pdf"));
        PdfFormField sig = PdfFormField.createSignature(stp.getWriter());
        sig.setWidget(new Rectangle(100, 100, 500, 200), null);
        sig.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
        sig.put(PdfName.DA, new PdfString("/Helv 0 Tf 0 g"));
        sig.setFieldName("Signature1");
        sig.setPage(1);
        stp.addAnnotation(sig, 1);
        stp.close();
```